# Proving Two Complexes are Not Quasi-Isomorphic

Tags: homological-algebra

In Richard Thomas' paper "[Derived Categories for the Working Mathematician](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0001045.pdf)" he mentions (page 6) that the two complexes
$$
\begin{align*}
C^\bullet&= \mathbb{C}[x,y]^{\oplus 2}\xrightarrow{(x,y)}\mathbb{C}[x,y]\\
D^\bullet&= \mathbb{C}[x,y]\xrightarrow{0}\mathbb{C}
\end{align*}
$$
have the same cohomology but are not quasi-isomorphic. Proving that $C^\bullet$ and $D^\bullet$ have the same cohomology is straightforward, but I'm having trouble proving that they are not quasi-isomorphic. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess we are working with $\Bbb C[x,y]$-modules.

The degree-zero part of the quasi-isomorphism would have to be a morphism $\Bbb C[x,y] \oplus \Bbb C[x,y] \to \Bbb C[x,y]$ inducing an isomorphism between $K$ and $\Bbb C[x,y]$, where $K$ is the kernel of the differential of $C^*$, that is
$$ K = \{ (y R, x R) \, | \, R \in \Bbb C[x,y]\}.$$

But such a morphism is necessary of the form $(P,Q) \mapsto PU + QV$, so it would map $K$ into the ideal $x \Bbb C[x,y] + y \Bbb C[x,y] \varsubsetneq \Bbb C[x,y]$, a contradiction.

Comment: Short story shorter: $K$ is abstractly isomorphic to $\Bbb C[x,y]$, but no ambient morphism $\Bbb C[x,y] \oplus \Bbb C[x,y] \to \Bbb C[x,y]$ restricts to such an isomorphism.

Comment: Oh. I guess this was a lot easier than I thought. Nice answer!

Comment: This proves that there does not exist a quasi-isomorphism $C^\bullet\to D^\bullet$. But (according to the definition of "quasi-isomorphic" complexes given in the cited paper) we should prove that it is impossible to find a third complex $E^\bullet$ with quasi-isomorphisms $E^\bullet\to C^\bullet$ and $E^\bullet\to D^\bullet$.

Comment: There is a missing minus sign: the kernel consists of those pairs (-yR,xR) with R in C[x,y]. Of course it doesn't change the proof.

Answer (score 6):

As was pointed out by Andrea in the comments to the other answer, the other answer does not answer the question properly.

An argument that the two complexes cannot be quasi-isomorphic in the general sense is sketched on page 2 of:

https://www.math.upenn.edu/~tpantev/rtg09bc/secnotes/ainfnity.davidovich.pdf

Answer (score 0):

As this is a (the?) standard example of a pair of complexes whose homologies agree despite their being non-isomorphic in the derived category, it is perhaps worth spelling out a proof here. Instead of $\mathbb{C}$, we'll work over a arbitrary commutative ring $R$ (in the category of $R\left[x,y\right]$-modules); the argument works in generality.

---

First, remark that your latter complex admits an evident quasiisomorphism from the (bounded, objectwise projective) complex $$0\to R\left[x,y\right]\oplus 0\overset{\begin{pmatrix}y \\ -x\end{pmatrix}\ \oplus\ 0}{\to} R\left[x,y\right]^{2}\oplus R\left[x,y\right]\overset{\begin{pmatrix}x & y\end{pmatrix}\ \oplus\ 0}{\to} R\left[x,y\right]\oplus 0 \to 0$$ (by replacing the direct summand $R\left[x,y\right]$ with its [Koszul resolution](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Koszul+complex#idea)). We'd like to show that this is not isomorphic in the derived category to the (bounded, objectwise projective) complex $$0\to 0\to R\left[x,y\right]^{2}\overset{\begin{pmatrix}x & y\end{pmatrix}}{\to} R\left[x,y\right]^{1} \to 0\text{.}$$ But (e.g., as a corollary of [Stacks Lemma 0649(1)](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0649)), bounded, objectwise projective complexes are isomorphic in the derived category iff they're homotopy equivalent. Homotopy equivalence of chain complexes is in turn a purely diagrammatic condition, so is conserved by all additive functors. In particular, the tensoring functor $-\otimes_{R\left[x,y\right]}R\left[x,y\right]/\left(x,y\right)$ is an additive functor which sends the two complexes to $$0\to R\left[x,y\right]/\left(x,y\right)\overset{0}{\to} \left(R\left[x,y\right]/\left(x,y\right)\right)^{2}\oplus R\left[x,y\right]/\left(x,y\right)\overset{0}{\to} R\left[x,y\right]/\left(x,y\right) \to 0$$ and $$0\to 0\to \left(R\left[x,y\right]/\left(x,y\right)\right)^{2}\overset{0}{\to} R\left[x,y\right]/\left(x,y\right) \to 0$$ respectively. But the homologies disagree, so these latter two are not chain homotopy equivalent, and thus neither are the former two!

---

Remark: When exhibiting examples of non-homotopy-equivalent CW complexes with the same homotopy groups (as is done [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/3544/131309)), the two are often distinguished by their (co)homology groups. Here we distinguish two complexes with the same homologies by constrasting the homologies of their $-\otimes_{R\left[x,y\right]}^{\mathbb{L}}R\left[x,y\right]/\left(x,y\right)$s.